# Content in iOS app doesn't 'stretch' when iPhone turned to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, orientation

I was just wondering how get the content in my view to stretch across the screen when i rotate the device? Currently it is just hugging the left hand side of the screen and makes it very hard to look at...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `AutoresizingMasks` in interface builder (right most tab in the right pane) or in your code, or you can set the frames manually, when the device is rotated (in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` for example)